# Fixing soap differences with wcf service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ebay-api

I am building a wcf web service, and I am trying to connect it to notification recieved from ebay.

My current status is that the notifications are recieved, but instead of getting to the right method with a parameter data, It reaches a method with action="*", meaning it acually cant find matching method.

I tryed calling my method using my own code and compared the soap body to the ebay soap body, so i can see the differences.

ebay soap body:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
    <GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <Timestamp>2008-02-13T03:47:28.106Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID>137541140</CorrelationID>
      <Version>553</Version>
      <Build>e553_core_Bundled_6057805_R1</Build>
      <NotificationEventName>ItemSold</NotificationEventName>
      <RecipientUserID>Seller1</RecipientUserID>
      <Item>
        .
    .
    .
    .
      </Item>
    </GetItemResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

The packed i send from my test client is:

```
  <s:Body>
    <FixedPriceTransaction xmlns="http://developer.ebay.com/notification">
      <GetItemTransactionsResponse xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBay.Service.Core.Soap" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:mAck>Warning</a:mAck>
        <a:mAckSpecified>true</a:mAckSpecified>
        <a:mAny i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
        <a:mBotBlock i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mBuild>915</a:mBuild>
        <a:mCorrelationID i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mDuplicateInvocationDetails i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mEIASToken i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mErrors i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
        <a:mExternalUserData i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mHardExpirationWarning i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mMessage i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mNotificationEventName i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mNotificationSignature i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mRecipientUserID i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mTimestamp> 0001-01-01T00:00:00 </a:mTimestamp>
        <a:mTimestampSpecified> false </a:mTimestampSpecified>
        <a:mVersion i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mHasMoreTransactions> false </a:mHasMoreTransactions>
        <a:mHasMoreTransactionsSpecified> false </a:mHasMoreTransactionsSpecified>
        <a:mItem i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mPageNumber> 0 </a:mPageNumber>
        <a:mPageNumberSpecified> false </a:mPageNumberSpecified>
        <a:mPaginationResult i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mPayPalPreferred> false </a:mPayPalPreferred>
        <a:mPayPalPreferredSpecified> false </a:mPayPalPreferredSpecified>
        <a:mReturnedTransactionCountActual> 0 </a:mReturnedTransactionCountActual>
        <a:mReturnedTransactionCountActualSpecified> false </a:mReturnedTransactionCountActualSpecified>
        <a:mTransactionArray i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
        <a:mTransactionsPerPage>0</a:mTransactionsPerPage>
        <a:mTransactionsPerPageSpecified> false </a:mTransactionsPerPageSpecified>
      </GetItemTransactionsResponse>
    </FixedPriceTransaction>
  </s:Body>
```

Couple of things to ignore:

1. I removed the header from both examples because it contains mustUnderstand=0, and because it reaches the method with action="*", so the header is probably fine.
2. The data content is different between the examples because i created an empty parameter for my test. And removed much of the irrelevant data from ebay example.

My Interface Method:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://developer.ebay.com/notification")]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://TestDomain.com/DropshipService.svc/Software/FixedPriceTransaction", IsOneWay = true)]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Software/FixedPriceTransaction", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        void FixedPriceTransaction(GetItemTransactionsResponseType GetItemTransactionsResponse);
```

The Main differences as i see it:

1. Somewhy in my example theres GetItemTransactionsResponse inside FixedPriceTransaction although i used in the interface BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare. Why? and how can i fix it?
2. Somewhy in my example theres a:m on every line. In ebay's example theres none. How can i remove it?
3. How do i remove all the namespaces i have in my example and why are they there by default?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605482/multiple-operations-with-soapaction-in-a-wcf-service-contract

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you don't want `WebInvoke`.

Comment: I eventually reached a situation where i try to deserialize the soap body myself and call the right method manualy. But i dont know how to tell it to expect the same naming without the m at the beginning...

Comment: I dont know if routing using body element in the example is good enaugh. I try to deserialize it myself and i got different xml format like shown in the above (m in the beggining, and a different namespace), so i guess it wont work because of the same reason i fail to do it myself right now.